Fire JS after element is added/attached
Currently, it's not possible to define an event handler on an element which will fire when the element is attached/added to the DOM.
<div id="data" onattach="this.innerText = someConfig.something.data"></div>

Is there another way to have this work without using an external script? E.g., not:
function setData() {
    document.getElementById("data").innerText = someConfig.something.data;

    // or

    const parentNode = document.getElementById("dataParent");
    const observer = new MutationObserver(nodes => {
        const node = nodes.find(n => n.id === "data");

        if (node) {
            node.innerText = someConfig.something.data;
        }
    });

    observer.observe(parentNode, { childList: true });
}

If not, are there any plans in upcoming JS/ES spec for this sort of feature? I was not able to find anything.

A MutationObserver ?

Custom elements do not count, right? Like, using connectedCallback()?

Specifically not via MutationObserver because this requires JS outside of the element itself in order to work. The goal is that the element's onattach (or similar) function is automatically called when the element itself is attached within the DOM tree.

Custom elements probably do not count here but I'm not 100% sure without more context.

I updated the description for clarity.
